# how to keep value of variable after making it null

Tags: javascript

I know its sounds silly but I am just asking, is there any way of keeping the value of `b` variable after we delete `a` variable?

```
var a = 'some string or number';
var b = a;

delete a;

but b is still = 'some string or number';
```

or any other way to keep the `b` value?

Comment: You are not playing around with the references. Values will always be copied.

Comment: maybe you some more examples. should `b` be deleted, too?

Comment: any alternate ?

Comment: What do you wish to achieve? Retain value of `b` even after deleting `a` or both should be deleted?

Comment: Retain value of b even after deleting a

Comment: That is happening already. Also `delete a` will not work as `delete` works on object. You can though reset value as `a=""` or `a=undefined`

Comment: your code is already working it's just delete is not working

Comment: Why do you think it's not keeping the value of `b`?

Answer (score 0):

`delete` does not *delete* values or variables, but **deletes properties on an object** (MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

For instance:

```
var myObj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
delete myObj.a;
// myObj === { b: 2 }
```

Of course you can just keep a reference to the value in another variable: `var copy = myObj.a` (before you delete the property). The variable will then hold the value (for primitives like basic numbers, strings, booleans) or reference (for objects etc.). Either way, your *copy* will hold the value still after the original property has been deleted:

```
var obj = { a: "hello" };
var copy = obj.a;
delete obj.a;
console.log(copy); // "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete only deletes the property of an object not a variable,

```
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
delete person.age;
```

So the variable "b" in the code you have mentioned will retain the value of "a".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a in you case, you have to define a by:

`window.a = 'some string or number';`

Then delete it by:

`delete window.a;`

or just

`delete a;`

`delete` in javascript just deletes the property, doesn't delete the value that property points to. The value might be gone because there is no more reference point to it.

And in your case, the value of `a` is a string, so, after to assign `a` to `b`, `b` has its own value "copied" from `a`. When you delete `a` successfully, the value of a is also lost, but the value of `b` is still intact.

Comment: Probably shouldn't use `window.prop` to demonstrate this, as there are several browsers (read browser versions) which don't remove properties on the window (http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#delete_and_host_objects) : "_Variable and function declarations in Global and Function code always create properties with DontDelete_"